# Sum of two squares

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, number-theory

Given a nonnegative integer \$n\$, determine whether \$n\$ can be expressed as the sum of two square numbers, that is \$\exists a,b\in\mathbb Z\$ such that \$n=a^2+b^2\$.

```
   0 -> truthy
   1 -> truthy
   2 -> truthy
   3 -> falsy
   4 -> truthy
   5 -> truthy
   6 -> falsy
   7 -> falsy
  11 -> falsy
9997 -> truthy
9999 -> falsy
```

Relevant OEIS sequences:

- [A001481](https://oeis.org/A001481) - should return truthy
- [A022544](https://oeis.org/A022544) - should return falsy

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer as measured in bytes wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64812/count-sums-of-two-squares "Count sums of two squares"), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28169/four-squares-together "Four Squares Together"), [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21951/78186).

Comment: Do we have to handle negative inputs?

Comment: Can we output 2 consistent values instead of 'truthy' and 'falsy'?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen, I think it's default for [tag:decision-problem] (see [tag info](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/decision-problem/info)).

Comment: @hyper-neutrino No, nonnegative integers only. Updated the question to specify this.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
def f(n):[*{(n-2*x*x)**-2for x in range(n+1)}][n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BroJADEX3fEXjamYEI7iDzPZ9wdsRFoMUJcHOpNQEY/x2HuMzGren97an4SZnT4dl6bCHXpEua3NXlBVmNrM2Jit6zzDDQMCOTqhom@tHU1OzjP5k6yYZLsGzwCDI4v04JbFAn0K@3@syAQDhWxl4IFGUInV2AxtdxZPVP/1x44S6WtfuXAhr4kViF@cjBnnVf/n6nXuCGHPTtFrAOqqzvLFWPT3uzrhta1qIZi5tI3vr7gL77noU9XkvZQzoxBb6oZc/)

Numerics on this and the previous one may be fragile. I don't know whether `n**-2` is guaranteed to give the same value as `(-n)**-2`.

If necessary this can be fixed at the cost of 1 byte.

##### Old [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
def f(n):[*{(n-2*x*x)**-2 for x in range(n+1)}][n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BjoMwDEX3nMLqKkmhKswOlO2cYHaIRSimg0SdyLgSVdWzU0KrqWb7/J/9HW7y6@lrWTrsoVeky9rcFWWFmc2sjckK6D3DDAMBOzqjon2uH01NzTL6s62bZLgEzwKDIIv345REgT5CfjzqMgEA4VsZeCBRlCJ1dgc7XcWb1Yt@u3FCXa1rDy6ENfEm0cX5hEHe@g9f/@c2EGNumtYWsI7qLG@sVVuPuzNu35p2e8WlbWR/dQ@BfXc9ifq8lzIGdGIL/dDLEw)

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
def f(n):[*{(n-2*x*x)**2 for x in range(n+1)}-{0}][n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCoMwFAX3PcXHVX5aIdqd4rYn6E5cSP1phfIMaQoR8ewpoYVuZ4Zxa3gsOKc0iSWrwE2vN4Wy1lFH1romu3iKNIP8iLsoHCvey83sQ48hZYm/rIzh5kBEwa@N8zOCwkkwdQUV3OZ9@6WX8fkSzqXEm7jwi6/@LZw@)

##### Old [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes

```python
def f(n):[*{sorted({x*x,n-x*x})[1]for x in range(n+1)}][n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY2xCsIwFEV3v@LRKa9WaHBLce0XuIUMxbxoQV5CGiGl9NujQcHlDuccuGFND8/nUiw5cIJR6XZbfExkxZbb3PHpsztqaZyPkGFmiBPfSfBR4m40m1IF/4Xse1QHAEhxVSHOnAR3xPbSQIND/Ri@dJyeC2EtKd8opF98jS/C8gY)

### How

Signals by exit code: Errors out for True and returns without error for False. The error is triggered by trying to access list positions which are out of bounds if `n` is the sum of two squares. In the last two versions the special case a=b triggers a zero division error.

All versions avoid double loops. The first version does it rather clumsily by computing x^2 and n-x^2, taking the maximum and checking for collisions (by counting uniques). The convoluted way of taking the max catches the special case a=b.

The second version implements the same logic a bit smarter: instead of taking the maximum of two values it makes use of he observation that

```python
`n = a^2 + b^2`
```

can be rewritten

```python
`abs(n-2a^2) = abs(n-2b^2)`
```

instead of the absolute value we can also take squares. AS before we can check for collisions as long as we do not forget the special case a=b.

The last version takes the reciprocal such that the a=b case triggers a zero division error.

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 33 bytes

```r
function(n)all((n-(1:n)^2)^.5%%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxCsIwFEX3fsUDKU3gKSZaSwoOHXSSOuhcKKXBQH2pTTL49bGCIIjLHQ7n3CmS9S7crZbuEdqpd/uoA3XeWGLE22FgjJZMlMQbyZtVnqaCR9eO4/BkHVujQIkb3GKOOyxQCFRKFe9RHH@veZIswAY/Bg/GlZAdq9PlkIHRQDMAf@thDsBqkPBpEOwEWV19rfp8/WvGFw)

Outputs `NA` if `n` is not the sum of 2 squares, `FALSE` if `n` is the sum of 2 squares.

If we are restricted to `TRUE`/`FALSE` output, then add +4 bytes for [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/pfXJqbn2ZUXFiaWJRabPs/rTQvuSQzP08jT1MxMSdHQyNPV8PQKi9Oz1QzzkgTSKmqGmr@L04sKMip1EjWMNAx1DHSMdYx0THVMdMx1zE01LG0tDQHEZaaOihma/4HAA), or +3 bytes for [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYzLCsIwFET3/YoLUprAVUy0lhRcuNCVKGjdFkppMFCTmgfi18cIrtzMMHDO2KiNd@FhJHfP0NnBbaMMuvfKaKJpN46E6DlhtW4XJW05TZXnjEbXTdP4Jj1ZIkOOK1xjiRuskDEUQlTfEBT/32mWzcAEPwUPytVQNJfbvgAlQacNp3MD/j5AcsBI4PDTEIyF4rA7XhNsEmFfyg3xAw) if we can reverse the output.

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>88</s> <s>74</s> <s>67</s> <s>66</s> <s>64</s> 53 bytes

```c
a,b;f(n){for(a=n;~a*n;b=b?--b:--a)n*=a*a+b*b!=n;a=n;}
```

-14 bytes - thanks to Kevin Cruijssen
-7 bytes - by omitting return (using global variable)
-1 byte - by using `-` instead of `!=`
-2 bytes - thanks to AZTECCO
-11 bytes - thanks to AZTECCO x2

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcrBEoIgFEDRdXxF0gYo2rSTyG95D0WZQWwEpnEc@/TIVm3PvUb2xpSTC8bntjvekxu76/Agf4mp9Q53K3BBZVngq51mBjqoN4igUGMjJdZSAg9Cg4AzCqz2/Fu2MoILjK@EHJ45RVZZduMNTXNOw0JrasHHhXJFtvIx1kMfi3x9AQ)

Comment: Hi, welcome to CGCC. You can golf your answer by using `for`-loops instead of `while`-loops. Also, you currently have a hard-coded upper-bound of 2,000,000 (\$2\times1000^2\$), so you might want to mention that in your answer. Both shorter and more correct would be to use the input `n` instead of `1e3` though: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##Rc3fCoIwGAXwa32KWDffNEOvwpb1LN@m08FcsT@EiK/emhB0d36HA0dUoxDxqIzQoR8ON6/m4Tzd83/jfK8VT13EE2cSDF3l0wJ2hmHZMKwqupsn82SerCRggSUveNcZagcfrDk07BdqtsUZlQG65pmzaHrYX6GmlOXZK3gHEtq2vdAH8Tb4aSFXIlG7haTBFj9CahxdrN5f)

Comment: Also, if you haven't seen it yet, [tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2203/52210) and [tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read through. :)

Comment: Using a global variable as you did [it's not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24058/84844) , you can pass a pointer. Here a [small golf](https://tio.run/##RckxDsIgFADQWU6huEAtbi5i9Sz/0/JLQtEUGtM09eginVzfM4qMyUcXjJ/abn9LbujO/Z39JabWOyyWocaatBVBLvY5CmqgCfoDFWlQSm6EG2ABLFC@ghNWqIKmhvSaB3BByIWx3WtKURysuMgHT@OU@plfuQUfZy41W/PXWA8Us3r/AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online") for you, and welcome to code golf

Comment: @AZTECCO What does `g=g` mean?:)

Comment: See [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/108879). Magic GCC stuff. But if you use this trick, the language you're competing in is C (GCC -O0)

Comment: @badatgolf Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
2~SquaresR~#>0&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@9@oLriwNLEotTioTtnOQO1/QFFmXkm0soKunUJatHJsrIKagr6DQrWBjoKhjoKRjoKxjoKJjoKpjoKZjoI5UBAoamlpaQ4mLWv/AwA)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>41</s> 39 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 32 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with a `\`.

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).*

```r
function(n)n%in%outer(k<-(0:n)^2,k,`+`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTzNPNTNPNb@0JLVII9tGV8PAKk8zzkgnWydBO0Hzf5qGgSZXTmJBQU6lhqGVuU6aJleahqEhiLS0tDSH0paa/wE)

Comment: Wouldn't `n%in%outer(k,k,"+")` be shorter?

Comment: @Giuseppe, indeed, it would - thanks!

Comment: If you are prepared to be highly inefficient, you can check instead whether `2^n` is in `2^k %o% 2^k`, which is shorter than having to call `outer`: [37 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTyfb1ihOw8AqTzPOSNMoLk81M09VI1s1XzVb83@ahoEmV05iQUFOpYahlblOmiZXmoahoSbXfwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @RobinRyder, nice idea - I think it's worth a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks! [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242593/86301).

Answer (score 7):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 14 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⍵∊∘.+⍨×⍨0,⍳⍵}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37Uu/VRR9ejjhl62o96VxyeDiQMdB71bgaK1wIA&f=S1Mw4EpTMARiIyA2BmITIDYFYjMgNgfJGQIA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `RM`, 5 bytes

```
Ẋ²Ṡ=a
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJSTSIsIiIsIuG6isKy4bmgPWEiLCIiLCIwIl0=)

```
Ẋ     # Cartesian product of (implicit range) self with (implicit range) self
 ²    # Square each
  Ṡ   # Sums of each
    a # Do any... 
   =  # Equal the input?
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
~+Ċ~^₂ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v077SFdd3KOmpodbJ/z/b2lpaf4fAA)

If you put a variable name such as `Z` as argument, you’ll get the actual couple of values whose squared sum is the input.

#### Explanation

It’s a direct description of the problem:

```
~+Ċ        Get a couple of two values Ċ whose sum is the input
  Ċ~^₂ᵐ    Both elements of Ċ must be squares of some numbers
```

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 33 bytes

Returns a positive integer for Truthy, and `0` for Falsey.

```javascript
f=(n,x=1)=>x>n?!n:!(n%x)-f(n,x+2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrRCkBAFAXffcXxoPa2COUFy7cIK9K9WtL@/eJpmmn28RmvyW3nnbHMSwjWKE69Kcn0vuch5iZWnHjK7N91RcGKg2IYFC0YHeqfWlMEbBbq@4gwCV9yLPkh6@dteAE)

This is a trivial modification of [@MitchSchwartz's brilliant answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66181/88546) to *[Count sums of two squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64812/count-sums-of-two-squares)*.

#### Explanation

It can be proven that if \$ n \$ has more \$ 4k + 1 \$ divisors than \$ 4k + 3 \$ divisors, that it can be written as the sum of two squares. One way to achieve this would be to add `1` if `n%(4*k+1)==0`, and `-1` if `n%(4*k+3)==0`. Writing this down, we can see that the task comes down to computing the following alternating sum:

```js
!(n%1) - !(n%3) + !(n%5) - !(n%7) + ...
```

which can then be written as:

```js
!(n%1) - (!(n%3) - (!(n%5) - (!(n%7) - ... )))`
```

The base case of `!n` handles the special case where `n=0`, by returning `1` instead.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes

```r
function(n,k=2^(0:n)^2)2^n%in%(k%o%k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTyfb1ihOw8AqTzPOSNMoLk81M09VI1s1XzVb83@ahoEmV05iQUFOpYahlblOmiZXmoahoSbXfwA)

This checks whether \$2^n\$ can be written as \$2^{a^2}\times 2^{b^2}\$. This will rapidly run into numerical issues, but is shorter than [pajonk's similar answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242465/86301) because we can then use `%o%` instead of `outer`. Note that [Dominic's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242475/86301) remains 4 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## Regex (ECMAScript or better), 37 bytes

```
^((x(x*))(?=.*(?=\2*$)(\3+$))\4|){2}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@9bsIwFEZfhUYI7k0ak1DEgGuYOrAwtGNpJQsujlvjWLaBlJ9nT8NQqcu3nE86Ol/yKMPGaxfz4PSW/L623/TTemHp1Hsl9dI4gLOYj9L2E6CBJkWEhWBpN@tx2kdYP2V9xPXkipfxrd@mozOyWL9Fr60CZMHoDcH0MZ8g8iAKfqq0IQAjPMmt0ZYA8UHYgzF4UcKw4IyOMMyHyPUOwArFDFkVK5yPr1cdVnIFWjjpAy1tBPVefCD@AfoP7LxclLM7xlj5@pQs7VEave15aRXNeklm@K72wPWzIK6zDDth0iTMkyMZQSPby7ipwCNewmDguqQI94qSu0MM0XcXfru1RV5Oi18) - ECMAScript
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7LTsMwEPyVVbVqvHmQB48DjttUKldO3EixCmokS6YNdpCCjPn14IZKXEY7s7M70x@Mvp3evwANB6dPb3sNmPNARb3dPG1WHrqTYWhFwesVJweqC4xcb9RxgEV7XHAPjRa212pgURal9vPVDuFEplmZlnT4OJvW/2oRdLpHSfz8y4bEvWl0XZFr9HO5EwGLHb/kqgtFVYt5HaYkIac6YCwaIxghmIhA/ECOJieHdrmcy83dQvGS/3VFxb33Uj48bqWcXhgb2RgTsbW4igO0VYzE2usEidqbb3KVx2kqsvKu@AU) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb9MwFH3vr7hEQ7XT1ksH4gEvmgCBhMQArY9tkdzEab05TrCdNV3pby/XafiY1DzEvvcen@tzfO/Fo5jc5w9HVdaV9XCPMVMVizn8n2m80mdzVq5li5VB3ay0yiDTwjm4FcrAHvqc88Lj8lipHEqskJm3yqxB2LWbLyn4ja22Dj62may9qvDkAOCT0hKK1MhttyURy6pcMqxHlL9vikJamd9JkUsLqw72PEn@nOzDglLe93Vjz7ebwE@IS1eoQeRflJGE0hepabSmqiCOyZ@N0I5El3EcR5Tun0NPDIT4swR7ZPB/GZDgEhlWiHvgbpQOF2YYVs8Pp9zhu/BeWgM27XeotqxDA0c5urGqKi2Fgae0QEbJYZYJY1C6MnXjIYWgts@R2c55WTJlKIdeZwdjG@G@ytbjNTuLAXpDNN4dOU4gg4heYl@fL0FjOaCYq7XyJJrgIyDeg0mw8tl4HAPLamGdxIDoebKkYzDTs0WmpVn7zfUV3EBAwltcpktkzDbCzpdtr6eLzHTJ4Z21YudYobQm7XjYDjtTAIrKBm14jdQkHMx1aqa4jEYo8Fb4bIMOlchmWXmKSDe5Bgf8A5KfJoZtrahJ3yKr6t234k6YtcROydhQGpQWQEpsb3L0LrztE@1NrtCxrVVekvColD@l3jbhff6Va/TQFyR66SK0hPJD@AZhqo4/CGlJG1NKblIW429xFV9Qsng1uqB08foX3V8dLo5hfI7JZPom@Q0) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7RboMwDEXf@Qor4sGmEBE67QEW7UOASdVG20xpgpxUpdr27Yx02otl@foc3fkez97tV3OZPUcI91DyVH4G7zpgzUKI9Q1xwaUgwlcti20MTZETDvtdTjQ8fdNX85Ov22ev2kqNHRhdZ0fPYMG4ZJQhfhjXZmC1lWG2JqKoBGVgjmAnh5ZemhZsr0Zt@3rMIMEuwXxwpwmNi5gCKv82NdJO0eZLAp7k5RDfz8gliEUU7hGkxLQwcyLocdCq@y/jr1He2MQJQ2R0RGtdqef6Fw) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7fS8MwEMff/SvOUliu2tBW8WExSHFFfJkwfWtnUJZ1gZCVNGMVf/zrXTJ1D3dw3/t@vnd29/4xWuCwkK0cOmrkHmblS0mtfFtd/orT6ePD/GlR3ZfPFQPFMwb7jdISNG@l688A1Bp0neZLzqPGRMwvdJ1RmhZLBtKsvMMrtO@0cmSSTvAPoVqa1m0I3haeqT3vsROy3lowoAwEkbqtUCTPkNJgPI3ed8wi0RAlBoH/gGVBUOfhz27n@mNe@Dv3s1XGgfk/EXooIar5TIjxlZCBDAkiueM08a0pkhhJc3URIzbXX/hZfMfjmKX5TXYA) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNa8JAEL37K5ZlITMaNUmtRdbgpS0IpYe2N2OXmK4mNG6WzQqC9benE@mph33M13tvdmxpu@XKlpYJx1LGp5xNmHX6oJy2dV5oCKaT4UqpMq@9KpqjrWrtMshQZm/TNghZQG9PRXXQ/YDx2vgWlHpevzwphSGLkSRJWA4qU6lWe@C2cHqyy4tv7whUXR0rz0PGZ8litpg/JIt7jnKwbxyIKo2kqNM9qbfw/vG4fkWJF1btQdSb1rtaG4pwHG/TlGeGIw23px11qBxG4TjGnq/Ptm6@NPAxD2lcEr9oTsb33GVCpA0JEEZbOWDs5mz@cmGW6a1P0WiEZM3gdqFj7osShAvJrD@Xzj0E5yAUBhHZpV@xQl2UTb@XZPSVWLI@Z8LIK9lc/50VUHafAGc4DxFhlU6GBFkyFAjZ3UggZrMfvCRX0XXROJ5Hvw) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/RaoQwFER/ReSCiTaidunDhtCFPvcL1ILYuzWQ3kjMoqzNt1ttKX0ZOMMwzIx2RjcNaMwGTtUOP3Bpz2fCmV2S7Y2xhS0p5@xZ5ekuTZUCZ81jBpw3py@@VgG25PIQv9jPURt8j7mEuyrk1Trs@oGBiTRFoGm8eb5Cp8CIaTTaxyKW@sqgy3t7Iy@Mj6ojkCno6qINewEDUrUm3/44EkgY/OPy4Czj69Hh8tfO9wNOLFmSFIj/2ne@zk57FIOdfNhnlfKfI0F2f2k0YQQUQtgKUT4V3w) - .NET

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number. Uses a variant of the multiplication/squaring algorithm [explained in this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125237/its-hip-to-be-square/223201#223201).

Commented and indented:

```
^                  # tail = N = input number
(                  # subtract a perfect square from tail
    # subtract a nonzero perfect square from tail
    (x(x*))        # \2 = any positive integer; \3 = \2-1; tail -= \2
    (?=
        .*         # find the smallest value of tail that satisfies the following
        (?=\2*$)   # assert \2 divides tail
        (\3+$)     # assert \3 divides tail at least once; \4 = \2*\2 - \2
    )
    \4             # along with "tail -= \2" above, acts as "tail -= \2*\2"
|
    # or just subtract 0 from tail
){2}               # do this twice
$                  # assert that tail == 0
```

This can be generalized to sums of any number of squares by changing the `2` in `{2}` to the desired count.

## Regex (Perl / Java / PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.34 or later</sup></sub> / .NET), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
^(\1?(\2xx|^x)*){2}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5fa8IwFMW/ykWCzZ0tTQrbg2m0gnvd095WDU4sBDLtkg4ysuyrd7ETfLncc@6f8@tP1jyOH99ArIBgLseDAVKKJGW93bxuVhG6i6XESSbqlcAAuksKQ2/1eYBZe56JCI2Rrjd6oFmR5e7r3Q3pROUFzzmePq9L67vLko9LolBcf7mUeLCNqSsMjXnjO5kq24lbrr5Joms5jVO3WGDQHVCa@Qw8pCVEkL9QEltiIG4@n@AmtgTOxT8r0SLGqNTzy1apcU9bvqZt5f3P3uMDhiqScWQFf2J/) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU5BTsMwEPzKqrIab5socQ4I4bhNpXLlxI20VosayZJpg51KQcZ8hEsP8AM-wzd4AW5SxGV3Z2Z3Z94_mp3Rp--fpxcghoPTh8eNBpLyAEWxXNwvZh7qg6HEiowXM44OVB0QusaofQujaj_iHkotbKNVS6Mkiu1xa9twIuOExQx3z-el-T-bBR5viER-_mWD48aUusjRlfqBrUSo2YpffNUFElWIXg7TdIpO1UBp1EXQQVhCBPEGKTEpOmLH4z5cny0EZ3zIShT33kt5e7eU8vPY1sn115pWbE6rvOte1x1O0OWeDNLpr2UJu8oG8As) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJNb9swDL3nV3DGhkhpqiY57DDVKLZhAwas29Ae0xRQbDlRK9OeJDdOsvz2jHK8jwL1hSb59Kj3xAf1pM4f8sejKevKBXigXJhKjCT8X2mCsS/WnF7pljqDullak0FmlfdwrQzCHvqaDypQeKpMDiV12G1wBleg3MrPFxzC2lUbD5/aTNfBVHRyAPDZWA1FinrT/bJEZFWuBfUTLj80RaGdzm@0yrWDZQd7XmR/TvZpwbns5/pxkJt15GfMp0vSoPKvBjXj/FWKjbXcFMwL/bNR1rPkYjQaJZzvn0NPDIyFFwn2xBD@MhDBBTEsCfco/Vk6vMNhjEEeTrXDDxWCdggu7f9IbVnHAZ5LcmNZVVYrhF1aEKOWcJspRJJusG4CpBDV9jV2u/VBl8Igl9Dr7GBirfw33Qa6ZmcxQG@IpbsTxwmEhOgl9v35Aiy1I0r42prAknN6BMIHwAl1vmCgNXCiVs5rSpidTxZ8DDh9sSmsxlVYX87gCiIS3lGYLogxWys3X7S9ni7D6ULCe@fU1ovCWMva8bAddqYAFJWL2ugaKU4k4GWKUwpnZyTwWoVsTQ6VxOZEecpYt7lIC/6RyE8bIzZO1awfkVX19ntxo3CladJkjJxHpQWwksZjTt7Ft93x3uSKHNs4EzSLj8rlLg2uie/zr12Th6FgyRufkCVcHuI3iFt1vGd30yt2N2vbX/ctH/H97PD6GLflODmfvp38Bg) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVLNbhMxED5wy1MMESh2mmySHhDCXVUFgYREKWq5JankbLyJwetd7Nlm05An4dJD-wY8DU_DeHf5qZS9jGfm22_8fZ4f91_kjbz79QR1VuQOIaSRzqO-gP8rJWpzsObUSlXU6RTlwugEEiO9h3OpLeygrXmUSOEm10vIqMOu0Gm7AulWfjrngGuXbzy8rRJVoM7pzw7AO20UpLFVm_rIuqOzzxejJF-qLhevyzRVTi0vlVwqB4sa9rjI_vzZpinnop3rByg268DPmI8XpEEuP2irGOdPY1saw3XKfKS-ldJ4Gtzv97uc7x5DGwbG8CDBjhjwLwMRjIhhQbivwh_FvZnthYhi39T2nySichZc3J6iJM-KMMBzQW4s8twoaeE2TolRCbhKpLUkXduiRIghqG1r7GrrUWWRtlxAq7OGRWvpP6oK6Zq1xQCtIYbuThwNyBKildj2p3Mw1A6oyBdGI-sO6REIj2DH1HlvkdbARYV0XlHCzHQ85wOwk4PNyCi7wvXJMZxCQMIrCpM5MSZr6abzqtVTZ3YyF3DmnNz6KNXGsGrQq3q1KQBp7oI2ukZsxwLsSWwnFI6OSOC5xGRNDmXE5qKsyVi9uZYW_A2RNxsTbZwsWDsiyYvtRXop7UrRpPHAch6UpsAyGm-X5F1421vempyTYxunUbHwqFzcxujK8D7_2gV5iCnrPvddsoSLffg6YaseSkyHL39es9nklM2Oq-r7dcX7fHe8f9a07sPmNMe7h_Fw8mLcJL8B) - Java
[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lzh7Fq/2) / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVDNSsNAEMZrn2JZFrJjkzYJtVq2oRcVCuJBvTXtksZNG0w3YbOFQO0b-AZeCuIb-DQ-jZNWLx52dv6-75uZ949qXR2-z97GE3QIMyQitE9Jj1RGraRRVZGkijv93vlEynVSWJmWmyovlIl5DCJ-6NeOSxx8GSblSrUN2iptay7l7fTuRkpwSQBIicSik-tc1spyWqVG9ZZJ-mINGlnkm9xSl9BBOBqMhpfh6IKC6GSl4SyPfMGKKEP2mj8-XU_vQcCO5Blnxay2plAaPfCCeRTRWFPA5nq7xAqmXd_1AmjxqqmK8llx6lEX2wXi03KrbYsdhwiaIQFafy46hByV9W_M9Dg61tHrdgGlCT9eaJPYdM2ZcVGsPZdKLHcax2UaAMiuHTEHla7Ldi5BcJVAkDYmTIs9yuz_nZWD-NzazLv6WvA4mPA4bJrXRQPnsAv37FQ6_H2-Fwz9U_AD) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BaoQwFEV/ReSBydgM6qKLCaEDXfcLHAeCfVMD6YvEDIax@XarLaXLc7kc7h3djH4a0NoVvGo9fmDsTifCmZ2L9cou9Qu7NDF@XSM/8KVJsBbnp/zVfY7G4nvOJTxUJW/Oo@4HBjYzlIGh8R74AlqBFdNoTchFLs2NgT727k5B2JA1e6FUoNuqS5uAAanWUOh@EgkkLP5xvXNZ8mV3@OObDv2AEyticQDiv/GDL7M3AcXgppC2WbX850yQ205ZQ5gBpZTWStTP1Tc) - .NET

```
^                  # tail = N = input number
(                  # The following will be captured in \1
    \1?            # Optionally subtract the previous perfect square from tail
    (\2xx|^x)*     # If on the first iteration, subtract a perfect square from tail;
                   # if on the second iteration and "\1?" was evaluated once,
                   # combines with it to subtract a perfect square from tail that
                   # is greater than or equal to the previous one; if "\1?" was
                   # evaluated zero times, this adjusts the first perfect square
                   # subtracted, optionally increasing it to a larger one, which
                   # effectively makes the "other" perfect square zero.
){2}               # Iterate this twice
$                  # Assert that tail == 0
```

Comment: *This can be generalized to sums of any number of squares ...*, There is however a shorter version for sums of four or more squares ;)

Comment: @H.PWiz Haha, yep, [nice 0 byte regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda n:n in(n and(i//n)**2+(i%n)**2for i in range(n*n+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYpBCoAgFAWv8jfB1wK1dkI3aWOU9aFeIW06vVmbdsPMnPe1Huhy7Ie8hX2cAsGDBAwKmFiMgdK6rVmqD@KRSEqnFLDMDI3aKZVfjV87a5U/k@BiNJFRjgc)

Comment: Nice answer! If I understand this packing trick of the two ranges, shouldn't `range(n*n+1)` be `range((n+1)*(n+1))` or `range((n+1)**2)` to combine the two statements of `range(n+1)`?

Comment: @solid.py as I get it, you don't need to check the whole `range(n+1)` for both summands, as one of them will always be <= n/2.

Comment: @solid.py Pajonk explained it nicely. In addition, the complete range can be covered by `~n*~n (== -(n+1) * -(n+1))` for the same byte count.

Answer (score 3):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 125 bytes

```
(load library
(d V repeat-val
(d R(q((N)(map* *(0to N)(0to N
(q((N)(any(map* contains?(V(map* s(V N(a N 1))(R N))(a N 1))(R N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy7DsIgGIV3n@KMP01MitfRN2BoE/Zf24EEAYGY8PQI1sHp5Du3bFyxJoVayXpeYM09ciw7WqAR17By3r/Zdp7oRaQEPTkMGGjMHo2@0uP5F7MrW@XhXWbj0o30ZiTSUMRQkELQ1Nbin2pvYUb7GSFxwBEnnHHBFVKifgA)

Comment: You can make this an anonymous function submission by removing the `(d S` from your code (though not from the TIO version) to get 125 bytes. This is important because I'm about to post a different solution that ties your bytecount... ;)

Comment: @DLosc all right, I look forward to it!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŻpŻ²§i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7oKjuw9tOrQ8E8g8tPVw@7F2ncPthyc83DHf/f9/IwMA)

Outputs `0` for falsy, and a non-zero positive integer for truthy. The Footer in the TIO link simply splits the range \$[0, n]\$ into truthy (top line) and falsey (bottom line)

### How it works

```
ŻpŻ²§i - Main link. Takes n on the left
Ż      - Zero range; [0, 1, ..., n]
  Ż    - Zero range; [0, 1, ..., n]
 p     - Cartesian product
   ²   - Square everything
    §  - Sums of each pair
     i - Index of n, or 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÝãnOIå
```

Bugfixed and -2 bytes thanks to *@Mr.Xcoder*, making it now similar as *@emanresuA*'s Vyxal answer and [*@cairdCoinheringaahing*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242501/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8NzDi/P8PQ8v/f/f0AwA) or [verify the smaller test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w3MPL87zrzy89L/O/2gDHUMdIx1jHRMdUx0zHXMdCx1LHUOgoGEsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý       # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input]
 ã      # Create all possible pairs with the cartesian product
  n     # Square each integer
   O    # Sum each inner pair
    Iå  # Check if this list contains the input
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Hi, Kevin, long time no see! :) I might be wrong but I think this fails for perfect squares (partitions don't also include `0`, right?)

Comment: Also, I think `ÝãnOsk` might save 2 bytes (with falsy output `-1` and truthy output any nonnegative integer)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Long time no see indeed. How are you doing? :) And thanks for the bugfix and -2. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>31</s> 26 bytes

```
.+
$*
^((^1|11\2)*\1?){2}$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLK05DI86wxtAwxkhTK8bQXrPaqFbl/38DLkMuIy5jLhMuUy4zLnMuQ0MuS0tLcxBhCQA) Link includes test cases. Edit: Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Deadcode. Explanation: `^((^1|11\2)*)` matches a square number at the beginning of the string. Repeating the expression with `{2}` does not in itself change this, but it allows the use of `\1?` to add a square number matched on the first iteration. (The first stage simply converts the decimal input to unary.)

Comment: -5 bytes by [using a twice-executed loop instead](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLK04jxtBew9AwxqgmzlBTS7PaqFbl/38DLkMuIy5jLhMuUy4zLnMuQ0MuS0tLcxBhCQA "Retina 0.8.2 – Try It Online").

Comment: @Deadcode Bah, my fault for adapting my answer https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132845 which does more work than it needs to. But why does the placement of the `\1?` matter?

Comment: I realized after my above reply that I hadn't correctly explained why it works, and was thus second-guessing the placement of the `\1?`. Now that I've [explained it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242646/17216), I can see that its placement does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
0y&:U&+m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36BSzSpUTTv3/39LAwA)

([Or this version for larger inputs](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36AyIk7NKlRNO/f/f0tLS3MA))

1 for truthy, 0 for falsy. (Thanks to @Giuseppe for -1 byte and this neater output.)

Square every number from 0 upto the input, add all the combinations of them, and check if the input is in there. (The "larger inputs" version does the sensible - but non-golfy - thing of limiting the check upto the square root of the given number; same logic, two extra bytes, a lot less resource hunger.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/excel), 64 bytes

```
=LET(x,SEQUENCE(SQRT(A1)+1,,1)^2,1-AND(ISERROR(XMATCH(A1-x,x))))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnhqES3qUXNTMPOcY?e=acImqD)

List all \$k^2\$ in \$[0..n]\$. Match all \$n - k^2\$ to list.  If all matches are errors, then false, otherwise true.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 52 bytes

```
a=.5
f(n)=min(ceil(mod((n-[0...floor(n^a)]^2)^a,1)))
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a7t3uxhoc4)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a5k9tooxd3)

#### 47 bytes (doesn't work past 100 because of Desmos 10000 element restriction)

```
l=[0...n]
f(n)=min(sign([aa+bb-nfora=l,b=l])^2)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ueloh5qkkp)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mfqgggvtvi)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 25 bytes

Returns 0 for truthy and 1 for falsy. Quite short considering it's a conventional language.

```matlab
@(n)0||(k=0:n).^2+k.^2'-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI0/ToKZGI9vWwCpPUy/OSDsbSKjr5v1PtI2OteZKyy9SyFSwVTCwMjTgAgolWmfqpGlkagKlUvNSuBL/AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), <s>125</s> <s>117</s> 109 bytes

```lisp
(d X(q((N I)(i(l N 1)N(X(s N I)(a I 2
(d S(q((I N)(i(a(X I 1)(X(s N I)1))(i(l N I)0(S(a I 1)N))1
(q((N)(S 0 N
```

The last line is an anonymous function that takes a number and returns 1 if it is the sum of two squares, 0 otherwise. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0xDsMgAAP3vMKjvUGkfiESCwsLK1UWJNqkSZa8ngJSu57u7Cu/75LPvVauiPyQHk7MLPCw8ow8MVCCwzw1K3TLwXcrMTZs9desfrGTYRhVm5FsT5dxIAYY@MqypRUlP4903Jr4SjsW0Fwb5odUvw)

#### Ungolfed/explanation

*Look, ma, no library!*

First, we define a helper function `X` that takes a number `N` and determines if it is (not) a square. A perfect square is the sum of consecutive odd numbers; therefore, subtracting the sum of the first several odd numbers from `N` (for an appropriate value of "several") will result in 0 if `N` is square. Thus, we recurse over increasingly large odd numbers (which we track as `I`) and subtract each one from `N` until `N` equals 0 (in which case `N` is square) or `N` is less than 0 (in which case `N` is not square):

```lisp
(def not-square?        ; Define not-square?
  (lambda (N I)         ; as a function of two arguments:
    (if (less? N 1)     ;  If N is less than 1,
      N                 ;  return N (0 if square, negative if not square)
      (not-square?      ;  Else, recurse with these arguments:
        (sub2 N I)      ;   New N is previous N minus current odd number
        (add2 I 2)))))  ;   New I is the next odd number
```

Next, we'll define a function `S` that determines whether a number `N` is the sum of two squares. Our algorithm here is to recurse over integers `I` starting at 0: if `I` is not square, or `N` minus `I` is not square, try the next `I` until `N` is less than `I`, at which point `N` cannot be the sum of two squares. On the other hand, if `I` and `N` minus `I` are both square, then `N` is the sum of two squares.

```lisp
(def sum-squares?           ; Define sum-squares?
  (lambda (I N)             ; as a function of two arguments:
    (if                     ;  If
      (add2                 ;   the sum of
        (not-square?        ;    0 if
          (sub2 N I)        ;    N minus I
          1)                ;    is square, < 0 otherwise
                            ;   and
        (not-square? I 1))  ;    0 if I is square, < 0 otherwise
                            ;  is truthy (nonzero), then:
      (if (less? N I)       ;   If N is less than I
        0                   ;   then return 0
        (sum-squares?       ;   Else, recurse with these arguments:
          (add2 I 1)        ;    New I is the next integer
          N))               ;    Same N
      1                     ;  Else (I and N minus I are both square), return 1
```

Finally, our submission is an anonymous function that takes `N` only and passes it to `sum-squares?` with a starting `I` of 0:

```lisp
(lambda (N)
  (sum-squares? 0 N))
```

Comment: Yeesh, I'm going to have to start some bounties for library-less answers that outgolf me

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), <s>49</s> 35 bytes

```
~n=1 in[i^2+j^2==n for i=0:n,j=0:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZPNbtswEITveQodbVQFNPwTWcB9kSABfAlqw1UD1wHcS17dnW977YEENDNL7g5H54/L6aj74/G5HTSdtufTa/pyfk2Hwza9/bpOp8PybZvP7C@P2/Xj9uPP4XmZJ81TmqcyT3We@jwNI6DZq3mtXoaTsWRFMpasya7JLsr@ztYU88VHFWuK@ervak31OdX1zVyzvplv/l7NreZWY93abr4b63Th@mFs@NzR6YeGFrEVNvpaaDS6jDajz4QkJbbKRm2OYZDQpgoH0KQKWEFCv6JRVSRteXl6ejteftsfg5aBxtGIkXm5huu4LVmVjCfruJMrs7lsPFubwawv@GyMHri94Ju5am3lAaytxumiWt98TnNNowvjzXgzvhpfXbNav9Ke8RVPzXVrO54a78Y7T2rt8DnD3DA3XDfMj3hrhloYfmGshVkXXIkUxNgxdwwekytYagmFmF6ML7KhFA8BiwUiJ8IIkRZhh3K8CxJSI2KjEt6iwxURH@GLCJFquE4t/ohACYdErNQiq7C4pBaPiASTRNJEzIRfWiPUSLBLZE6YJlwTtqlH5jmAJIooCg@FiRrx@rBjOCjv19N2u2y7n8f33f3r98/dfT9P/36v/f7/bGTL5OMv)

Thanks to MarcMush we can save a lot more! We can also replace `f(n)` with the slightly shorter version `~n`!

Comment: you can shave of some bytes by removing `&&true` and `√` (maybe also by using `any`)

Comment: @MarcMush nice! I've shortened the function as well!

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>28</s> 23 bytes

```julia
~n=n∈(N=(0:n).^2).+N'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZNNbtRAFIT3OYV32MJErv5zN9JwhFwAgTQbRNAwisJEGjZZ55xcZKjvsWXRLbmqXvd71eUfL6fHo6632@v5cP7z9jY/HObt43m5/5qW@/cP726X55fL99@Hz9s6aZ3SOpV1quvU12kYAc1ezWv3MpyMJSuSsWRNdk12UfZ3tqaYLz6qWFPMV39Xa6rPqa5v5pr1zXzz925uN7cb69Z2891YpwvXD2PD545OPzS0ia2w0ddGo9FltBl9JiQpsVU2anMMg4Q2VTiAJlXAChL6FY2qImnbl7u7b8fTL/tj0DLQOBoxMi/XcB23JauS8WQdd3JlNpeNZ2szmPUFn43RA7cXfDNXra08gLXVOF1U65vPaa5pdGG8GW/Gd@O7a3brd9ozvuOpuW5tx1Pj3XjnSa0dPmeYG@aG64b5EW/NUBvDb4y1MeuGK5GCGDvmjsFjcgVLLaEQ04vxRTaU4iFgsUDkRBgh0iLsUI53QUJqRGxUwlt0uCLiI3wRIVIN16nFHxEo4ZCIlVpkFRaX1OIRkWCSSJqImfBLe4QaCXaJzAnThGvCNvXIPAeQRBFF4aEwUSNeH3YMB@Xp@fF8OZ3nn8en@frh0@t8Xdbp3@@1LP9nI1smb38B)

Based on [David Scholz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242869/101725)’s solution.

Thanks to dingledooper for shaving 5 bytes

Comment: 23 bytes: `~n=n in(N=(0:n).^2).+N'`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```ruby
->n{(k=0..n).any?{|a|k.any?{|b|a*a+b*b==n}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWiPb1kBPL09TLzGv0r66JrEmG8pKqknUStRO0kqytc2rra39X6CgAVRoaKipl5tYoKGWpvkfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda n:(r:=range(n+1))and n in(i*i+j*j for i in r for j in r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcwxCoAwDEDRq2RMWgfFRQrexCVSqykaS3Dx9FV0e/zhl/vaTu2HYjWNU935mCODBrQwGuu6oPqOiDWCgiiKE59dhnQayBvAPuaPVIuJXugOLpga@Add2xJRfQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔Ｘ…·⁰θ²η⊙η⊙η⁼θ⁺ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05rLsbg4Mz1PIyC/HCjgmZecU1qcWZYalJiXnqphoKNQqKmjYATEGUClAUWZeSUajnmVGhk6ClDKtbA0MadYo1BHIQCoUyNTRyFHEwSs//@3tLQ0/69blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
≔Ｘ…·⁰θ²η
```

Generate a list of squares from `0` to `n²` inclusive (in case `n<2`).

```
⊙η⊙η⁼θ⁺ιλ
```

Check whether any pair sums to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```hs
f n=or[n==x*x+y*y|x<-[0..n],y<-[0..x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzza/KDrP1rZCq0K7UquypsJGN9pATy8vVqcSwqqIjf2fm5iZp2CrkJtY4BuvUFBaElxS5JOnEK1RnJFfrpCnqa2tpKCkrQ3hqigADdWsyYPoNjQwAOoHAA)

- Thanks to @ovs for saving 3 Bytes.

Comment: `elem n[...` saves 2, `or[n==...` saves 3

Answer (score 1):

## [MATLAB](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 43 bytes

```matlab
o=@(x)any(~mod(sqrt(x-(0:(x/2)^.5).^2),1));
```

taking advantage of vectorized code to search from 0 to sqrt(x/2), checking sqrt(x - i^2) is an integer with mod([],1)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/39ZBo0IzMa9Soy43P0WjuLCoRKNCV8PASqNC30gzTs9UUy/OSFPHUFPT@v9/AA)

Comment: I don't really know MATLAB, but I *think* you should be able to get down to [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCMzEnRyM3P0WjuLCoRKNCV8PAqiJOz1RTL85IU8dQU/N/vi0Rqqy58jWMTDT/AwA) by not assigning to ```o``` (so leaving it as an anonymous function definition), swapping ```(x/2)``` for just ```x```, and outputting the other way around (so ```1``` for *not* sum of 2 squares) by removing ```~``` and changing to ```all```...

Comment: You're right. I didn't realize my truthy value could be 0, and falsy be 1. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## k (ngn/k), 37 bytes

```
c:{0<#&x{x=+/y}/:+{(%x)=_%x}#'!2#1+x}
```

try it in the [ngn/k repl](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#r)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 47 bytes

```
f(n)=\prod_{a=0}^n\prod_{b=0}^n\{aa+bb=n:0,1\}
```

The leading newline is necessary for the piecewise to paste properly.

Outputs 0 for truthy and 1 for falsey.

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fggeb7ut8d)

The [`∏` trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236800/68261) didn't work, maybe due to the `\{aa+bb=n:0,1\}` piecewise. Avoiding it with `sign(aa+bb-n)^2` or `0^{(aa+bb-n)^2}` ended up longer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 15 bytes

```
JqS[GZ2CB)++j~[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9dlPnfqzA42j3KyNlJU1s7qy76f2lBbXlO4H8DLkMuIy5jLhMuUy4zLnMuQ0MuS0tLcxBhCQA)

Horribly inefficient for falsy, but works

```
J   # Duplicate input (n)
qS[ # Quoted square
GZ  # Generate squares [0..n)
2CB # All combinations of pairs 
)++ # Sum each pair
j   # Swap stack
~[  # n in list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 71 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>(m=n)?[...Array(++m*m).keys()].some(i=>(i%n)**2+(~~(i/n))**2==n):0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NbsIwEITP5CmWQ8U6Dg7KqSI4Fc@BerDAoW79g/wTKULw6qmNOM3sfLOaXzGJcPbqFrfT57KM3PIBDbfk68QYO3ovZqTU1IawPzkHJN8sOCNR5Zr6sKSuO4rPJ6rWknLw/LrfLaPzgJPwoIDDrs9ygO6llBK4V6vCvAxJx1xYr0dUpIe2Beu8EVoFCUJriD7FnxkmoZMMEF0JMrGXFx2FDnNJi5FQNl2KtxSr1dnZ4LRk2l1RNbDZDpvmvUf66rH8Aw)

Not great but might as well post it since I spent an hour trying.

Answer (score 0):

## [F#](https://fsharp.org/), 66 bytes

```
let a t=Seq.allPairs[0..t][0..t]|>Seq.tryFind(fun(f,s)->f*f+s*s=t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxCsIwEIb3PsVRENpqQxc3E3DQueAYMhzaSCBNNDkFoe8e0/SGn@P7/jsd@7sPU0p2IkAgfpveDK0d0YQoB8ZIbbmI1VD4XY17NPrjGn2IbS90p/exi5zaJE8XlwujN46EqtaPMxoHGJ5f4BXkWRl5Qgu8YCYHBYuAfFF8CdwqZc/uFbLVDurdua4KHFI6/gE)

Straight-forward: create two lists from 0 to total, `Seq.allPairs` gets the Cartesian product between the two, and `Seq.tryFind` tries to find the pair that, when squared and added together, equals the total `t`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ė2Ṛ²ʂƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCU5NjIlRTElQjklOUElQzIlQjIlQ0ElODIlQzYlODcmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lMjAlMjAlMjAwJTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElMjAlMjAlMjAxJTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElMjAlMjAlMjAyJTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElMjAlMjAlMjAzJTIwLSUzRSUyMDAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjA0JTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElMjAlMjAlMjA1JTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElMjAlMjAlMjA2JTIwLSUzRSUyMDAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjA3JTIwLSUzRSUyMDAlMEElMjAlMjAlMjA4JTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElMjAlMjAlMjA5JTIwLSUzRSUyMDElMEElMjAlMjAxMCUyMC0lM0UlMjAxJTBBJTIwJTIwMTElMjAtJTNFJTIwMCZmbGFncz1D)

*Very* slow for large inputs.

##### Explanation

```python
Ė2Ṛ²ʂƇ  # Implicit input
Ė       # Push [0..input]
 2Ṛ     # Combinations with
        # replacement with
        # a length of two
   ²    # Square (vectorised)
    ʂ   # Sum each inner list
     Ƈ  # Contains the input?
        # Implicit output
```