# Decompose number N into the sum of three triangular numbers

Tags: number, arithmetic, number-theory, fastest-algorithm

It is known that any natural number can be decomposed into the sum of three triangular numbers (assuming 0 is triangular), according to [Fermat's Polygonal Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_polygonal_number_theorem). Your task is to come up with an algorithm of decomposing number into 3 triangular numbers that has the best asymptotic complexity. As an input you are given a number N. Output should contain three numbers, they must be triangular(or 0) and sum of them must be equal to number given in the input.

---

The difference between this [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132834/three-triangular-numbers) and mine is that my question isn't code-golf.

Comment: The problem is equivalent to finding a 3-square decomposition because $$a(a+1)/2 + b(b+1)/2 + c(c+1)/2 = n \iff (2a+1)^2 + (2b+1)^2 + (2c+1)^2 = 8n + 3$$ and I point to [a paper](http://pollack.uga.edu/finding3squares-6.pdf) that shows some of the fastest known algorithms that can solve that. But note that time complexity analyses of these algorithms are ***extremely*** high-level, and without assuming a long-standing conjecture, the time bound is simply not known (other than it being polynomial in the number of bits of the input).

Comment: So, while I do think it is an interesting problem in itself, I don't think it fits well with our site under the contest type [tag:fastest-algorithm] - as we can't prove the time complexity of the best known algorithms, we can't decide which one wins.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question based on my comments above: we can't decide the winner for this challenge under the given winning criterion.